# How can I split a column that contains a persons full name into First Name Surname?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and SSMS.

How can I split a column that contains a persons full name into a First Name and Surname column?

For example In the column I have the name 'Jonathon Smith Roberts'. I'd like to split the name so that 'Jonathon' goes in the First Name column and 'Smith Roberts' in the Surname column.

Comment: Could you possibly provide the code associated with what you're doing, would help with figuring out what you're trying to produce?

Comment: I've added some more information. I hope it makes the question clearer.

Comment: What about Carl van der Walt and Samuel L Jackson?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql):

```
SELECT FullName
      ,PARSENAME (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', '.'), 2) AS FirstName
      ,PARSENAME (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', '.'), 1) AS LastName
FROM TableName;
```